# Cannot re-assign $this?

Tags: php, message, php4

I have a script on a server that had php version 4. Now it is changed to php5 and the script does not function any more. I get this error:

Fatal error: Cannot re-assign $this in URL database.php line 88

In the file is a class that has a function. Inside is the line 88:

```
$this = new $db( $serv, $user, $pass, $dbName );
```

What does the error mean and how can I change it?

Comment: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php There is an explanation of $this here.

Answer (score 3):

`$this` is a special "variable" that always refers to the *object* the current function is executing in. It only makes sense inside functions that belong to a *class*; however, you are not allowed to use it anywhere else, and you may never assign to it. The solution is simply to rename the variable.

Comment: Well, I renamed it to dbo, but that only gives me a new error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function: doquery() in URL QuizOperations.php on line 524

Line 524

$this->db->doQuery( ..... );

There are several functions with similar lines.

If I changes these this variables to dbo, I get the same error message.

Comment: @Atha: Is this your own code or code you have obtained from somewhere else? Is it written for PHP 4 or 5? Anyways, the source of the problem is a bit hard to tell from just that line, and since it is a different kind of error, you're probably better off posting it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can reassign $this value by variable variable

```
$name = 'this';
$$name = 'stack';
echo $this;
```

// this will result stack

Answer (score 0):

The class is attempting to re-define itself ($`this` in php is the same as `this` in C#) and it can't be done. You should change `$this` to something else and the error should be gone then.

Answer (score 0):

`$this` is a reserved variable name and cannot manually be assigned a value.

Answer (score 0):

*$this* is a predefined variable in PHP.

Here's the reference in the PHP manual: Classes and Objects: The Basics. It describes how, inside a method, $this points to "this object" that is being operated upon. It is still reserved outside a method, though.

Change the identifier to another word.