# How to cast a parent class to its child class in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, casting, php-7

Is it possible to cast a parent class to its child in PHP? If not, what is the most efficient alternative to effecting this?

For example, the following results in an error:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public $test;
    public static function create(): self {
        $a = new self();
        $a->test = 123;
        return $a;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public $baz;
    public static function create(): self {
        $b = (self) parent::create(); // <--- Is this possible?
        $b->baz = 456;
        return $b;
    }
}

$bar = Bar::create();

var_dump($bar); /* should output:
  object(Bar)[35]
    public 'baz' => int 456
    public 'test' => int 123 */
```

Comment: What is `(self)` supposed to achieve? It is not a valid cast per http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: It's attempting to cast the result of `Foo::create()` as an instance of `Bar`.

Comment: array and stdClass object casting is special.because they rely on under-the-hood code and stdClass has no methods, just properties so it is simple to cast.

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve if you were to `var_dump( $bar );`?

Comment: `var_dump($bar)` should output `object(Bar)`.

Comment: I am sure that your example is oversimplified but changing line #10 into `return new Bar();` would achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: That's correct, my apologies. Class `Foo` contains properties that `Bar` is supposed to inherit. I'll update the question.

Comment: `Bar::create()` would need to grab a `Foo()` object, grab a `Bar()` object, loop the `Foo()` and add it's properties into the `Bar()` and return `Bar()`

Comment: Please refer to my previous comment about casting arrays and stdClass objects. The fact of the matter is that you cannot use `self` to cast you complex object even though you can use `self` to typehint the method return.

Comment: Your question about casting does not match the code implementation. A question about cast but your code about Inheritance. see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Comment: @tecdocukrnet The selected answer solves the problem I was facing, whether that solution involved `casting` or an alternative approach. When I asked the question, the only way I had in mind was via casting.

Comment: @reformed Regarding the casting, it seems to me that the best ideas are here - both in the question and the answers. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958315/cannot-re-assign-this-use-reference-of-an-existing-object-a-into-another-objec

Comment: @tecdocukrnet thanks. I've also found that, with PHP 8.0, the `static` [return type](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/static-return-type) makes this easier.

Comment: It was possible to create an object and return it from a static method before. But all the same, I don't understand how the static return type makes this easier? It would be interesting if you gave your answer.

Comment: The problem was not with casting, but with returning a child class from a parent method. I said casting because that's the only thing I could think of at the time. `static` return type resolves that problem. That was my problem, and my problem was resolved. If you want to learn more about casting, you can post your own question about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement this using the following strategy:

```
class Foo {
    public $test;
    public static function create(array $row): self {
        $a = new static();
        $a->test = $row['Test'];
        return $a;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public $baz;
    public static function create(array $row): Foo {
        $b = parent::create($row);
        $b->baz = $row['Baz'];
        return $b;
    }
}

$test = Bar::create([
    'Test' => 123,
    'Baz' => 456,
]);

var_dump($test);
/* Outputs:
    object(Bar)#2 (2) {
        ["baz"]=> int(456)
        ["test"]=> int(123)
    } */
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare that `Bar` extends `Foo`, the default `Foo` constructor calls the `Bar` constructor in order to initialise its parent properties (in this case, `public $test`). If you define a custom constructor for your child classes, you should also call the parent constructor. [This section of the PHP documentation describes how this works](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#example-191):

```
<?php
class BaseClass {
    function __construct() {
        print "In BaseClass constructor\n";
    }
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        print "In SubClass constructor\n";
    }
}

class OtherSubClass extends BaseClass {
    // inherits BaseClass's constructor
}

// In BaseClass constructor
$obj = new BaseClass();

// In BaseClass constructor
// In SubClass constructor
$obj = new SubClass();

// In BaseClass constructor
$obj = new OtherSubClass();
```

For the specific functionality in your example, I would prefer putting the logic of the code into protected constructors and calling them from the factory method:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public $test;

    protected function __construct() {
        $this->test = 123;
    }

    public static function create(): Foo {
        return new self();
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public $baz;

    protected function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->baz = 456;
    }

    public static function create(): Foo {
        return new self();
    }
}
```

Notice that I have changed the return type of the function `create()` to always be `Foo`. PHP will not allow you to change the return types of functions being overwritten from a parent class, and using `self` in both instances will do that.

However, it's not a problem. `Bar::create()` gives us a `Bar` object set up as you would expect. The return type just has to be compatible with `Foo`, and since `Bar` implements `Foo`'s interface it is considered type-compatible.

You could simplify this code down even further using the [`static`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) keyword:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public $test;

    protected function __construct() {
        $this->test = 123;
    }

    public static function create(): Foo {
        return new static();
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public $baz;

    protected function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->baz = 456;
    }
}

var_dump(Bar::create()); /* Outputs:
    object(Bar)#1 (2) {
    ["baz"]=>
    int(456)
    ["test"]=>
    int(123)
    }
*/
```

It may be that using protected constructors isn't an option, e.g. because you already have a public constructor with required arguments or a similar situation. In this case you would have to resort to what is explained in the other answers, creating a temporary `Foo` and copying property values over to a new `Bar` object:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public $test;

    public static function create(): Foo {
        $result = new self();
        $result->test = 123;
        return $result;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public $baz;

    public static function create(): Foo {
        $foo = parent::create();
        $result = new self();
        foreach($foo as $property => $value) {
            $result->$property = $value;
        }
        $result->baz = 456;
        return $result;
    }
}

var_dump(Bar::create()); /* Outputs:
    object(Bar)#2 (2) {
    ["baz"]=>
    int(456)
    ["test"]=>
    int(123)
    }
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for this excellent information. It appears as though making `Bar`'s constructor public, and then calling `var_dump(new Bar());` returns the same (desired) output as `Bar::create()` in your provided code. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, that's the exact behaviour expected. There are valid reasons to make constructors only available internally to the class (such as the Factory Method pattern, i.e. your create() may return different object types for different reasons), but if all you want is to use a `new Bar` where you would normally use a `Foo` object, then just constructing a `Bar` is sufficient (see: [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). In fact, this is the crux of object-oriented programming - writing code that targets an interface (`Foo`), not an implementation (`Bar`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything built-in that does this. You'll can write a function in the child class that takes an instance of the parent class and returns a child with the same contents.

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    public static function FooFromBar($foo) {
        $bar = new Bar();
        $bar->prop1 = $foo->prop1;
        $bar->prop2 = $foo->prop2;
        // continue for all properties
        return $bar;
    }
}
```